# how to start jboss in background

Tags: jboss7.x, admin

i'm using centos 6 and jboss 7.1.1 final. i using this command to start jboss:./domain.sh,when it start,it output a lot of logs,and the worst thing is just when i disconnect the ssh,the server is down.i've already tried another command ./domain.sh &  ,nothing changes.
in the domain.sh,it says,

```
     if [ "x$LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND" = "x" ]; then
      # Execute the JVM in the foreground
      eval \"$JAVA\" -D\"[Process Controller]\" $PROCESS_CONTROLLER_JAVA_OPTS \
         \"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/process-controller.log\" \
         \"-Dlogging.configuration=file:$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR/logging.properties\" \
         -jar \"$JBOSS_HOME/jboss-modules.jar\" \
         -mp \"${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}\" \
         org.jboss.as.process-controller \
         -jboss-home \"$JBOSS_HOME\" \
         -jvm \"$JAVA_FROM_JVM\" \
         -mp \"${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}\" \
         -- \
         \"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/host-controller.log\" \
         \"-Dlogging.configuration=file:$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR/logging.properties\" \
         $HOST_CONTROLLER_JAVA_OPTS \
         -- \
         -default-jvm \"$JAVA_FROM_JVM\" \
         "$@"
      JBOSS_STATUS=$?
   else
      # Execute the JVM in the background
      eval \"$JAVA\" -D\"[Process Controller]\" $PROCESS_CONTROLLER_JAVA_OPTS \
         \"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/process-controller.log\" \
         \"-Dlogging.configuration=file:$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR/logging.properties\" \
         -jar \"$JBOSS_HOME/jboss-modules.jar\" \
         -mp \"${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}\" \
         org.jboss.as.process-controller \
         -jboss-home \"$JBOSS_HOME\" \
         -jvm \"$JAVA_FROM_JVM\" \
         -mp \"${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}\" \
         -- \
         \"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/host-controller.log\" \
         \"-Dlogging.configuration=file:$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR/logging.properties\" \
         $HOST_CONTROLLER_JAVA_OPTS \
         -- \
         -default-jvm \"$JAVA_FROM_JVM\" \
         "$@" "&"
      JBOSS_PID=$!
      # Trap common signals and relay them to the jboss process
      trap "kill -HUP  $JBOSS_PID" HUP
      trap "kill -TERM $JBOSS_PID" INT
      trap "kill -QUIT $JBOSS_PID" QUIT
      trap "kill -PIPE $JBOSS_PID" PIPE
      trap "kill -TERM $JBOSS_PID" TERM
      if [ "x$JBOSS_PIDFILE" != "x" ]; then
        echo $JBOSS_PID > $JBOSS_PIDFILE
      fi
      # Wait until the background process exits
      WAIT_STATUS=128
      while [ "$WAIT_STATUS" -ge 128 ]; do
         wait $JBOSS_PID 2>/dev/null
         WAIT_STATUS=$?
         if [ "$WAIT_STATUS" -gt 128 ]; then
            SIGNAL=`expr $WAIT_STATUS - 128`
            SIGNAL_NAME=`kill -l $SIGNAL`
            echo "*** JBossAS process ($JBOSS_PID) received $SIGNAL_NAME signal ***" >&2
         fi
      done
      if [ "$WAIT_STATUS" -lt 127 ]; then
         JBOSS_STATUS=$WAIT_STATUS
      else
         JBOSS_STATUS=0
      fi
      if [ "$JBOSS_STATUS" -ne 10 ]; then
            # Wait for a complete shudown
            wait $JBOSS_PID 2>/dev/null
      fi
      if [ "x$JBOSS_PIDFILE" != "x" ]; then
            grep "$JBOSS_PID" $JBOSS_PIDFILE && rm $JBOSS_PIDFILE
      fi
   fi
   if [ "$JBOSS_STATUS" -eq 10 ]; then
      echo "Restarting JBoss..."
   else
      exit $JBOSS_STATUS
   fi
```

i tried to remove the if clause,but there is no miracle

or how to install the jboss 7 as service.thanks a lot.

Comment: Better ask this on serverfault.com or possibly superuser.com, since it's more of an administration problem than a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the implementation of Xientd service. Try to run the script as a daemon/service. Try to add your own service with Xientd. Once you have started or triggered the service, It will run in the server even you have closed the SSH. See the followings links to get further awareness to set up your own service.

[link1](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.in/2010/01/how-to-add-custom-new-service-under.html)

[link2](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-do-i-configure-xinetd-service/)

[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514893/linux-how-to-make-a-deamon-service-usable-with-xinetd)

These are comes with pure Linux administration stuffs but easy create your own. You should select a port dedicated for this service and make sure to open this port via firewall.

I hope this will help you